# Android-activity not found exception ...but already declared in the manifest

Tags: android

I was tring to declare an application to use a java file with global variable to share them between more than one activity, I changed the name of my application, I changed the name of the manifest, probably I messed up something, then I changed the names again, now some activities no longer work, it seems like they are not declared in the manifest, but **they are**! Somebody have some idea of what may be the solution of the problem?

class island

```
package it.magussoftware.iknowyou;

import it.magussoftware.iknowyou.*;
import it.magussoftware.iknowyou.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Island extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    int nDomanda;
    int nLanguage=0;//((iknowyou)getApplication()).getnLanguage();
    MediaPlayer zapScelta, zapRivela; 

    String sProfilo="           YOUR PROFILE \n\n"; 
    Button bRisposta1,bRisposta2,bRisposta3;
    TextView tDomanda,tProfilo;
    Intent Back = new Intent(Island.this, Main.class);

    void back(){startActivity(Back);}


    void MostraProfilo(){
        tProfilo.setText(" " + sProfilo);
        tDomanda.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bRisposta1.setText("Back to Main Menu");
        bRisposta2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bRisposta3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        zapRivela.start();
    }


    void AggiornaProfilo1(int nDomanda,int nLanguage){
        switch (nLanguage){
        case 0:
            switch (nDomanda) {
                case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_1_1));
                    break;
                case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_2_1));
                    break;
                case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_3_1));
                    break;
                case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_4_1));
                    break;
                case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_5_1));
                    break;
                case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_6_1));
                    break;
                case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_7_1));
                    break;
                case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_8_1));

                    MostraProfilo();
                    break;
                default:
                    back();
                break;
            }
            break;  
        case 1: 
            switch (nDomanda) {
            case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_1_1));
                break;
            case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_2_1));
                break;
            case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_3_1));
                break;
            case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_4_1));
                break;
            case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_5_1));
                break;
            case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_6_1));
                break;
            case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_7_1));
                break;
            case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_8_1));

                MostraProfilo();
                break;
            default:
                back();
            break;
        }
        break;  

        }

    }
    void AggiornaProfilo2(int nDomanda,int nLanguage){
        switch (nLanguage) {
        case 0:
            switch (nDomanda) {
            case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_1_2));
                break;
            case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_2_2));
                break;
            case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_3_2));
                break;
            case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_4_2));
                break;
            case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_5_2));
                break;
            case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_6_2));
                break;
            case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_7_2));
                break;
            case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_8_2));
                MostraProfilo();
                break;
            default:
                back();
                break;
                }
            break;

        case 1:
            switch (nDomanda) {
            case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_1_2));
                break;
            case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_2_2));
                break;
            case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_3_2));
                break;
            case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_4_2));
                break;
            case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_5_2));
                break;
            case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_6_2));
                break;
            case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_7_2));
                break;
            case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_8_2));
                MostraProfilo();
                break;
            default:
                back();
                break;
                }
            break;

        }

    }
    void AggiornaProfilo3(int nDomanda,int nLanguage){
        switch(nLanguage){
        case 0:
            switch (nDomanda) {

            case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_1_3));
                break;
            case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_2_3));
                break;
            case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_3_3));
                break;
            case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_4_3));
                break;
            case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_5_3));
                break;
            case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_6_3));
                break;
            case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_7_3));
                break;
            case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_profilo_8_3));
                MostraProfilo();
                break;
            default:
                back();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 1: 
            switch (nDomanda) {

            case 0: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_1_3));
                break;
            case 1: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_2_3));
                break;
            case 2: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_3_3));
                break;
            case 3: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_4_3));
                break;
            case 4: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_5_3));
                break;
            case 5: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_6_3));
                break;
            case 6: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_7_3));
                break;
            case 7: sProfilo=sProfilo.concat(getString(R.string.isola_ita_profilo_8_3));
                MostraProfilo();
                break;
            default:
                back();
                break;
            }
            break;
        };

    }
    void AggiornaDomande(int nDomanda,int nLanguage){
        switch (nLanguage){
        case 0:

            switch (nDomanda) {
            case 1: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_2));
                    bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_2_1));
                    bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_2_2));
                    bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_2_3));
                    zapScelta.start();
                    break;
            case 2: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_3));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_3_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_3_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_3_3));     
                zapScelta.start();    
            break;
            case 3: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_4));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_4_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_4_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_4_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();       
                break;
            case 4: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_5));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_5_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_5_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_5_3)); 

                zapScelta.start();
                break;
            case 5: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_6));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_6_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_6_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_6_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break; 
            case 6: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_7));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_7_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_7_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_7_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break; 
            case 7: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_domanda_8));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_8_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_8_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_risposta_8_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (nDomanda) {
            case 1: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_2));
                    bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_2_1));
                    bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_2_2));
                    bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_2_3));
                    zapScelta.start();
                    break;
            case 2: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_3));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_3_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_3_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_3_3));     
                zapScelta.start();    
            break;
            case 3: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_4));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_4_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_4_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_4_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();       
                break;
            case 4: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_5));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_5_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_5_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_5_3)); 

                zapScelta.start();
                break;
            case 5: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_6));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_6_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_6_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_6_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break; 
            case 6: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_7));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_7_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_7_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_7_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break; 
            case 7: 
                tDomanda.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_domanda_8));
                bRisposta1.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_8_1));
                bRisposta2.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_8_2));
                bRisposta3.setText(getString(R.string.isola_ita_risposta_8_3)); 
                zapScelta.start();
                break;
            }
            break;

        }

    }    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isola);


        zapScelta= MediaPlayer.create(Island.this, R.raw.scelta1);
        zapRivela=MediaPlayer.create(Island.this, R.raw.reveal_profile);

        nDomanda=0;
        tDomanda=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tDomanda);
        tProfilo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tProfilo);

        bRisposta1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bRisposta1);
        bRisposta2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bRisposta2);
        bRisposta3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bRisposta3);


        bRisposta1.setOnClickListener(this);

        bRisposta2.setOnClickListener(this);

        bRisposta3.setOnClickListener(this);    

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bRisposta1:
            AggiornaProfilo1(nDomanda, nLanguage);
            nDomanda++;
            AggiornaDomande(nDomanda, nLanguage);
        break;

        case R.id.bRisposta2:
            AggiornaProfilo2(nDomanda, nLanguage);
            nDomanda++;
            AggiornaDomande(nDomanda, nLanguage);
        break;

        case R.id.bRisposta3:
            AggiornaProfilo3(nDomanda, nLanguage);
            nDomanda++;
            AggiornaDomande(nDomanda, nLanguage);
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Logcat

```
    05-06 15:56:37.810: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1124 objects / 83944 bytes in 85ms
05-06 15:56:46.190: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM
05-06 15:56:46.190: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{it.magussoftware.iknowyou/it.magussoftware.iknowyou.Castle}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2678)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at it.magussoftware.iknowyou.Castle.<init>(Castle.java:23)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-06 15:56:46.220: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  ... 11 more
05-06 15:56:55.280: D/dalvikvm(289): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1146 objects / 84800 bytes in 75ms
05-06 15:57:00.570: D/AndroidRuntime(289): Shutting down VM
05-06 15:57:00.570: W/dalvikvm(289): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{it.magussoftware.iknowyou/it.magussoftware.iknowyou.Island}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2678)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at it.magussoftware.iknowyou.Island.<init>(Island.java:23)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-06 15:57:00.650: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  ... 11 more
05-06 15:57:03.310: I/Process(289): Sending signal. PID: 289 SIG: 9
```

Here's the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.magussoftware.iknowyou"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


     <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="it.magussoftware.iknowyou.SPLASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="it.magussoftware.iknowyou.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <activity 
      android:name=".Island"    
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>


    <activity 
      android:name=".Castle"    
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

    <activity 
      android:name=".Cube"    
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TestMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Language"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Instruction"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Credits"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Clean your project, rebuild, and try again.  If it still fails, post the specific error from logcat, the manifest, and at least the start of the java file defining that activity.

Comment: Roll back your changes in version control. You are using version control, right?

Comment: this always happens when you try to refactor the package name of the app. you should review all your hardcoded strings of paths(hope you don't use them), and also re-import manually each activity on the manifest. you can try with the graphical interface. remember that not everything on the manifestfile is replaced correctly on eclipse if you still have problems please post the information requested by @ChrisStratton so we can help you

Comment: copy your code, edit your question and paste it.Use sample code option to format your code.

Comment: I can't roll back, too late...how ca I post code it's the first time i use this forum @PedroTeran

Comment: click edit on your question and add the code, there is qoutemark for code on teh editor with this simbol {}

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did as you said but it still don't work, thanks for help anyway, I posted the informations, any idea?

Comment: You fail running an Activity called Island but neglect to provide its source, and provide only another instead.  Also you do not seem to provide the full stack trace.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs as a result of this line

```
   Intent Back = new Intent(Island.this, Main.class);
```

Because your Activity is not a fully functional Context until the start of the call to onCreate().

Initialize your Intent object only in or after onCreate().